# Get current timezone as `Region/City`

Tags: linux, date, timezone

Unfortunately [`timedatectl set-timezone` doesn't update `/etc/timezone`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/451709/143394).

How do I get the current timezone as `Region/City`, eg, given:

```
% timedatectl | grep zone
                       Time zone: Asia/Kuala_Lumpur (+08, +0800)
```

I can get the last part:

```
% date +"%Z %z"
+08 +0800
```

How do I get the`Asia/Kuala_Lumpur` part without getting all `awk`-ward?

I'm on Linux, but is there also a POSIX way?

Comment: Don't you have /etc/localtime as symbolic link to zoneinfo file? ( e.g. /etc/localtime -> ../usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Madrid )

In such case, you could get is by readlink /etc/localtime | sed "s[.*zoneinfo/[["

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [this comment by Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/451709/timedatectl-set-timezone-doesnt-update-etc-timezone#comment820348_451714), he said:

> `timedatectl` is a `systemd` thing that queries `timedated` over `dbus` and `timedated` derives the name of the timezone (like `Europe/London`) by doing a `readlink()` on `/etc/localtime`. If `/etc/localtime` is not a symlink, then that name cannot be derived as those timezone definition files don't contain that information.

Based on this and [tonioc's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/451705/get-current-timezone-as-region-city#comment820376_451705), I put together the following:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

if filename=$(readlink /etc/localtime); then
    # /etc/localtime is a symlink as expected
    timezone=${filename#*zoneinfo/}
    if [[ $timezone = "$filename" || ! $timezone =~ ^[^/]+/[^/]+$ ]]; then
        # not pointing to expected location or not Region/City
        >&2 echo "$filename points to an unexpected location"
        exit 1
    fi
    echo "$timezone"
else  # compare files by contents
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521114/getting-the-canonical-time-zone-name-in-shell-script#comment88637393_12523283
    find /usr/share/zoneinfo -type f ! -regex ".*/Etc/.*" -exec \
        cmp -s {} /etc/localtime \; -print | sed -e 's@.*/zoneinfo/@@' | head -n1
fi
```

Comment: [You have a good eye](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/451925/2), thanks for the update, @StephenKitt.

Answer (score 5):

For the time zone, you can use geolocation:

```
$ curl https://ipapi.co/timezone
America/Chicago
```

Or:

```
$ curl http://ip-api.com/line?fields=timezone
America/Chicago
```

http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/time#Time_zone