# `timedatectl set-timezone` doesn't update `/etc/timezone`

Tags: linux, arch-linux, date, timezone

I expected that `timedatectl` would update `/etc/timezone` when changing timezones, but no:

```
% sudo timedatectl set-timezone 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur'
% cat /etc/timezone
Asia/Bangkok
```

Is there a reason that it doesn't? (Bug?)

If I manually update `/etc/timezone` to match `timedatectl set-timezone`, are there any side-effects I should be aware of?

Is there anywhere else I should consider changing timezone, eg [xfce4 panel clock](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/227405/143394)?

Comment: I don't think many things use `/etc/timezone`, `localtime()` and co. don't. if `$TZ` is not set, what matters is /etc/localtime

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas [Java does use /etc/timezone](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16294/41737), apparently...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`timedatectl`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/timedatectl.html) updates [`/etc/localtime`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/localtime.html), which is the documented way of setting the default timezone in most Linux-based environments (along with its override, the `TZ` environment variable, which is the only [POSIX-defined way of specifying the timezone](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tzset.html)).

`/etc/timezone` appears to be mostly Debian-specific (including derivatives). On Debian systems, `timedatectl set-timezone` also updates `/etc/timezone`, in version of systemd [older than 252.6-1](https://tracker.debian.org/news/1424576/accepted-systemd-2526-1-source-into-unstable/) (so until Debian 11 included).

If you manually update `/etc/timezone`, you should also update the `/etc/localtime` symlink (and make sure you keep the latter a symlink). Updates to `/etc/localtime` appear to be taken into account by (most?) desktop environments, so there’s no need to use environment-specific tools to update the timezone.

If you’re running Debian, you should use `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` to configure the default timezone; that updates `/etc/localtime` and `/etc/timezone` as above, and it also updates the selected timezone in the debconf database (which serves as the default when configuring `tzdata`). If you don’t do this, the next time `tzdata` is updated, the timezone will be restored to the value in the debconf database. `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` also takes care of updating the SE Linux context, if you’re using SE Linux.

Comment: And to answer Tom's other question, timedatectl is a systemd thing that queries timedated over dbus and timedated derives the name of the timezone (like `Europe/London`) by doing a `readlink()` on `/etc/localtime`. If `/etc/localtime` is not a symlink, then that _name_ cannot be derived as those timezone definition files don't contain that information.

Comment: I use `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` on Debian to configure the system timezone. I assume it does what is needed. It does modify /etc/timezone and /etc/localtime

Comment: Thanks @Stéphane, good point about `dpkg-reconfigure`, running that is necessary to ensure the setting is preserved across package upgrades.

Comment: `On Debian systems, timedatectl set-timezone also updates /etc/timezone` - Hmm, not so on Manjaro (Arch-based). I've [let them know](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/timedatectl-set-timezone-doesnt-update-etc-timezone/50684).

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneChazelas, you may be interested in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/451925/143394) based on your comment.

Comment: @Nickolay no worries, thanks for bringing it to my attention!

Answer (score 2):

In the early days systemd (which `timedatectl` and `timedated` are parts of) used to update `/etc/timezone`. In [v190 (around 2012) this behavior was constrained to Debian](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/fe0acbf7e061eb5be2708f0dbb9275084abc97af/NEWS#L16158-L16162), which invented the file, and later the support was [moved from upstream](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/46a2911bf2780f616396df5671dd901cc7cb54fd#diff-154726f4ee806b177b7c9fc7dc4eca2b3de79eea864b8b3a11e21fa0cc209007L226) to distro patches. As far as I can see, Arch never supported this in [their package](https://gitlab.archlinux.org/archlinux/packaging/packages/systemd).

According to the NEWS entry of [systemd (253~rc2-1) experimental](https://salsa.debian.org/systemd-team/systemd/-/blob/8ce52334d889fc0a85d0fc00a6ed93c8030b6426/debian/NEWS), the Debian maintainers plan to drop this from their patchset as well:

> The Debian-specific /etc/timezone will no longer be supported by systemd-timedated, as it is no longer useful and its functionality has been subsumed into /etc/localtime, and tzdata will no longer create it.

*(There are recent messages on debian-users [talking about /etc/timezone being a legacy relic](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2023/12/msg01184.html), the apparent inconsistency between their messages and the [wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/TimeZoneChanges) on one hand, and what I experienced first-hand on an (admittedly not up-to-date) system on the other hand, is what prompted me to do this research.)*

Answer (score -2):

`/etc/timezone` is fully optional on UNIX. It is not used by any official system software.

The timezone you have in mind is typically inherited from `init(1)` via `login` to the shell.

From the documentation, `/etc/timezone` is intended to contain time zone names in relation to host or domainnames.

Comment: What's an _official system software_? What do you mean by _UNIX_? What documentation are you referring to?

Comment: Software delivered with the system. Typical UNIX systems are Solaris, AIX, HP-UX. FreeBSD.

Comment: Do any of those systems have a `timedatectl` command?

Comment: No, but the documented content of /etc/timezone is something like **US/Eastern          East.Sun.COM #Sun East Coast**. Is this what `timedatectl`sets up?

Comment: You seem to be referring to the /etc/timezone file used by the sysidtool software on Solaris to build NIS maps. It is specific to Solaris. `timedatectl` is a systemd utility to interact with its `timedated` service, which suggests the OP is running a GNU/Linux system using systemd's init framework, more specifically, probably a Debian-based one as that `/etc/timezone` file is mostly Debian-specific. See also http://0pointer.de/public/systemd-man/timezone.html, out-of-date as systemd no longer uses that file even on Debian.